# Source for R' Soloveitchik's teaching about why we don't stand for a baby in utero?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, torah-study, pregnancy-birth, malach-angel, rav-joseph-ber-soloveitchik

There's a famous teaching from [Niddah 30b](https://www.sefaria.org/Niddah.30b.47-55?lang=he&with=Rashi&lang2=he) that a baby is taught the entire Torah in utero.

Someone once referenced this *gemara* and asked [The Rav](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_B._Soloveitchik), if that's the case why don't we stand for a pregnant woman whenever she enters a room- aren't we [supposed to stand](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.19.32?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) for someone (ie the unborn baby) who knows *kol HaTorah kula*?

To which The Rav responded, that's not Torah that was acquired by "עמילות" i.e. "exerting oneself."

Anyone know the source for where I can find this teaching?

Comment: He is not in the same room!

Comment: I heard this from Rav Aron Kotler....

Comment: @AviM oh interesting! Happen to have a link?